# MVVM architecture with Interactors/UseCases

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

**Context**

So, I've been working with the MVVM architecture just for a couple of projects. I'm still trying to figure out and improve how the architecture works. I always worked with the MVP architecture, using the usual toolset, Dagger for DI, usually multi-module projects, the Presenter layer being injected with a bunch of Interactors/UseCases, and each Interactor being injected with different Repositories to perform the backend API calls.

Now that I've moved into MVVM I changed the Presenter layer by the ViewModel, the communication from the ViewModel to the UI layer is being done through LiveData instead of using a View callback interface, and so on.

Looks like this:

```kotlin
class ProductDetailViewModel @inject constructor(
    private val getProductsUseCase: GetProductsUseCase,
    private val getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase,
) : ViewModel(), GetProductsUseCase.Callback, GetUserInfoUseCase.Callback {
    // Sealed class used to represent the state of the ViewModel
    sealed class ProductDetailViewState {
        data class UserInfoFetched(
            val userInfo: UserInfo
        ) : ProductDetailViewState(),
        data class ProductListFetched(
            val products: List<Product>
        ) : ProductDetailViewState(),
        object ErrorFetchingInfo : ProductDetailViewState()
        object LoadingInfo : ProductDetailViewState()
    }
    ...
    // Live data to communicate back with the UI layer
    val state = MutableLiveData<ProductDetailViewState>()
    ...
    // region Implementation of the UseCases callbacks
    override fun onSuccessfullyFetchedProducts(products: List<Product>) {
        state.value = ProductDetailViewState.ProductListFetched(products)
    }
    
    override fun onErrorFetchingProducts(e: Exception) {
        state.value = ProductDetailViewState.ErrorFetchingInfo
    }
    
    override fun onSuccessfullyFetchedUserInfo(userInfo: UserInfo) {
        state.value = ProductDetailViewState.UserInfoFetched(userInfo)
    }
    
    override fun onErrorFetchingUserInfo(e: Exception) {
        state.value = ProductDetailViewState.ErrorFetchingInfo
    }
    
    // Functions to call the UseCases from the UI layer
    fun fetchUserProductInfo() {
        state.value = ProductDetailViewState.LoadingInfo
        getProductsUseCase.execute(this)
        getUserInfoUseCase.execute(this)
    }
}
```

There's no rocket science here, sometimes I change the implementation to use more than one LiveData property to keep track of the changes. By the way, this is just an example that I wrote on the fly, so don't expect it to compile. But It's just this, the ViewModel is injected with a bunch of UseCases, it implements the UseCases callback interfaces and when I get the results from the UseCases I communicate that to the UI layer through LiveData.

My UseCases usually look like this:

```kotlin
// UseCase interface
interface GetProductsUseCase {
    interface Callback {
        fun onSuccessfullyFetchedProducts(products: List<Product>)
        fun onErrorFetchingProducts(e: Exception)
    }
    fun execute(callback: Callback) 
}

// Actual implementation
class GetProductsUseCaseImpl(
    private val productRepository: ApiProductRepostory
) : GetProductsUseCase {
    override fun execute(callback: Callback) {
        productRepository.fetchProducts() // Fetches the products from the backend through Retrofit
            .subscribe(
                {
                    // onNext()
                    callback.onSuccessfullyFetchedProducts(it)
                },
                {
                    // onError()
                    callback.onErrorFetchingProducts(it)
                }
            )
    }
}
```

My Repository classes are usually wrappers for the Retrofit instance and they take care of setting the proper Scheduler so everything runs on the proper thread and mapping the backend responses into model classes. By backend responses I mean classes mapped with Gson (for example
a list of ApiProductResponse) and they get mapped into model classes (for example a List of Product which I use across the App)

**Question**

My question here is that since I started working with the MVVM architecture all the articles and all the examples, people is either injecting the Repositories right into the ViewModel (duplicating code to handle errors and mapping the responses) or either using the Single Source of Truth pattern (getting the information from Room using Room's Flowables). But I haven't seen anyone use UseCases with a ViewModel layer. I mean it's pretty handy, I get to keep things separated, I do the mapping of the backend responses within the UseCases, I handle any error there. But still, feels odds that I don't see anyone doing this, **is there some way to improve the UseCases to make them more friendly to the ViewModels in terms of API? Perform the communication between the UseCases and the ViewModels with something else than a callback interface?**

Please let me know if you need any more info about this. Sorry for the examples, I know that these are not the best, I just came out with something simple for sake of explaining it better.

Thanks,

**Edit #1**

This is how my Repository classes look like:

```kotlin
// ApiProductRepository interface
interface ApiProductRepository {
    fun fetchProducts(): Single<NetworkResponse<List<ApiProductResponse>>>
}

// Actual implementation
class ApiProductRepositoryImpl(
    private val retrofitApi: ApiProducts, // This is a Retrofit API interface
    private val uiScheduler: Scheduler, // AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
    private val backgroundScheduler: Scheduler, // Schedulers.io()
) : GetProductsUseCase {
    override fun fetchProducts(): Single<NetworkResponse<List<ApiProductResponse>>> {
        return retrofitApi.fetchProducts() // Does the API call using the Retrofit interface. I've the RxAdapter set.
            .wrapOnNetworkResponse() // Extended function that converts the Retrofit's Response object into a NetworkResponse class
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)
    }
}

// The network response class is a class that just carries the Retrofit's Response class status code
```

Comment: Have you found a correct solution?

Comment: Have you found a reason/case to not use UseCase/Interactor? I'm starting with MVVM approach and I'm not sure if they are unnecessary layer.

Comment: @Abbas No, actually I've used Use Cases on my latest project with MVVM. The only difference is that instead of using callbacks to communicate the Use Cases to the ViewModel I use RxJava.

Comment: @4gus71 Do you mean use RxJava with observsbles? So in ViewModel we subscribe to observable variable, pass it to Interactor method and update value in ViewModel through update observable variable in Interactor. Correct me if I am not right.

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy Actually on my Interactor I only have functions returning an Observable. On the ViewModel I call this functions, subscribe to the observable and do whatever I need to do.

For example, an Interactor to fetch a list of Orders would have a function:

`fun fetchOrders(): Observable<List<Order>> {...`

Then on the ViewModel I do:

`fetchOrdersInteractor.fetchOrders().subscribe {....}`

Something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your use case so that it returns `Single<List<Product>>`:

```kotlin
class GetProducts @Inject constructor(private val repository: ApiProductRepository) {
    operator fun invoke(): Single<List<Product>> {
        return repository.fetchProducts()
    }
}
```

Then, update your `ViewModel` so that it subscribes to the products stream:

```kotlin
class ProductDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getProducts: GetProducts
): ViewModel() {

    val state: LiveData<ProductDetailViewState> get() = _state
    private val _state = MutableLiveData<ProductDetailViewState>()

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    init {
        subscribeToProducts()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }

    private fun subscribeToProducts() {
        getProducts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.main())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    // onNext()
                    _state.value = ProductListFetched(products = it)
                },
                {
                    // onError()
                    _state.value = ErrorFetchingInfo
                }
            ).addTo(compositeDisposable)
    }

}

sealed class ProductDetailViewState {
    data class ProductListFetched(
        val products: List<Product>
    ): ProductDetailViewState()
    object ErrorFetchingInfo : ProductDetailViewState()
}
```

One thing I'm leaving out it is the adaptation of `List<ApiProductResponse>>` to `List<Product>` but that can be handled by mapping the list with a helper function.

Comment: Nice!!! I didn't know you could override the `invoke` on a class like that, it looks super clean! 

Answer (score 0):

I have just started using MVVM for the last 2 of my projects. I can share with you my process of dealing with **REST APIs in ViewModel**. Hope it will help you and others.

- Make a  **Generic Retrofit Executer** Class with their callbacks. which will take a retrofit call object and gives you data.
- Make a repository for Your particular package or module where you can handle all API request. in my case, I am getting one user by its id from API.
  **Here is User Repository.**

```html
class UserRepository {


    @Inject
    lateinit var mRetrofit: Retrofit

    init {
        MainApplication.appComponent!!.inject(this)
    }

    private val userApi = mRetrofit.create(UserApi::class.java)

    fun getUserbyId(id: Int): Single<NetworkResponse<User>> {
        return Single.create<NetworkResponse<User>>{
            emitter ->
            val callbyId = userApi.getUserbyId(id)
            GenericReqExecutor(callbyId).executeCallRequest(object : ExecutionListener<User>{
                override fun onSuccess(response: User) {
                    emitter.onSuccess(NetworkResponse(success = true,
                            response = response
                            ))
                }

                override fun onApiError(error: NetworkError) {
                    emitter.onSuccess(NetworkResponse(success = false,
                            response = User(),
                            networkError = error
                            ))
                }

                override fun onFailure(error: Throwable) {
                    emitter.onError(error)
                }

            })
        }
    }

}
```

- Then Use this Repository in your ViewModel. In my case here is my **LoginViewModel code**.

```html
 class LoginViewModel : ViewModel()  {

     var userRepo = UserRepository()

     fun getUserById(id :Int){
         var diposable = userRepo.getUserbyId(id).subscribe({

             //OnNext

         },{
             //onError
         })
     }
}
```

I hope this approach can help you to reduce some of your boilerplate code.
Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for dropping your feedback. I don't think that I'm struggling so much with making the API calls. I mean, you could get rid of some boilerplate code there just by using Retrofit's RxAdapter. No need to wrap the responses into Single's all by yourself. I added some more info on the post.

Comment: Also, I'm a little bit curious about how are you doing to communicate your results to the UI layer through LiveData. Could you add a brief example of that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when I started using MVVM a while ago. I came up with the following solution, based on Kotlin suspend functions and coroutines:

1. Change ApiProductRepositoryImpl.fetchProducts() to run synchronously. To do this, change your retrofit interface to return Call<...> and then change the repository implementation to

```kotlin
// error handling omitted for brevity
override fun fetchProducts() = retrofitApi.fetchProducts().execute().body()
```

2. Make your use cases implement the following interface:

```kotlin
interface UseCase<InputType, OutputType> {
    suspend fun execute(input: InputType): OutputType
}
```

so your GetProductsUseCase would look like this:

```kotlin
class GetProductsUseCase: UseCase<Unit, List<Product>> {
    suspend fun execute(input: Unit): List<Product> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        // withContext causes this block to run on a background thread 
        return@withContext productRepository.fetchProducts() 
}
```

3. Execute the use case in your ViewModel

```
launch {
   state.value = ProductDetailViewState.ProductListFetched(getProductsUseCase.execute())
}
```

See https://github.com/snellen/umvvm for more info and examples.